# Get value of hidden input field in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the value of a hidden input field using JS,

```
   var credoff = parseInt($(this).children('input.credoff:hidden').val());
```

which works fine in FF but does not work in IE, the input im talking of is the following...

```
<input type='hidden' value='$row->coff' class='credoff' name='credoff'/>
```

Comment: What is the context of `this`?

Comment: Could you show the **rendered html**, rather than the php(?) used to generate the mark-up? JavaScript, and therefore jQuery, work from the client-side code, not the server side. So it's helpful to see that there's no obvious errors in that code if something's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
var credoff = parseInt($(this).children('input[name="credoff"]').val());
```

Although I don't know what 'this' is. More code would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that did the trick! apologies for the lack of information

Answer (score 3):

Could you try `input[type='hidden']`?

Answer (score 1):

Are there many other elements with the 'credoff' class?

There are comments in the jQuery documentation for the :hidden selector related to this.

http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Apparently in IE, the :hidden selector also selects  elements, so it's possible that you're not getting back the right element. You could try

`var credoff = parseInt($(this).children('input.credoff:hidden').not('option').val());`

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
var credoff = parseInt($(':input[type:"hidden"][name:"credoff"]').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

var credoff = parseInt($(this).children('input[name="credoff"][type="hidden"]').val());